# How can I reduce time complexity of the following program?

Tags: c, rotation

**Question:**

Mark is an undergraduate student and he is interested in rotation. A conveyor belt competition is going on in the town which Mark wants to win. In the competition, there's A conveyor belt which can be represented as a strip of 1xN blocks. Each block has a number written on it. The belt keeps rotating in such a way that after each rotation, each block is shifted to left of it and the first block goes to last position.

There is a switch near the conveyer belt which can stop the belt. Each participant would be given a single chance to stop the belt and his PMEAN would be calculated.

PMEAN is calculated using the sequence which is there on the belt when it stops. The participant having highest PMEAN is the winner. There can be multiple winners.

Mark wants to be among the winners. What PMEAN he should try to get which guarantees him to be the winner.

```
PMEAN=∑i=1ni×a[i]
```

where a represents the configuration of conveyor belt when it is stopped. Indexing starts from 1.

**Input Format**

```
First line contains N denoting the number of elements on the belt. 

Second line contains N space separated integers.
```

**Output Format**

```
Output the required PMEAN
```

**Constraints**

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^6 
-10^9 ≤ each number ≤ 10^9
```

For any rotation, PMEAN will always lie within the range of 64-bit signed integer.

**Sample Input**

```
3
20 30 10
```

**Sample Output**

```
140
```

**Explanation**

Number on top can be written in these manners.

Initial numbers on belt, `

```
20 30 10 
PMEAN = 1x20 + 2x30 + 3x10 = 110`
```

After first rotation,

```
30 10 20 
PMEAN = 1x30 + 2x10 + 3x20 = 110
```

After second rotation,

```
10 20 30 
PMEAN = 1x10 + 2x20 + 3x30 = 140
```

So maximum possible value will be 140.

**Code:**

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int b[n],a[n],k,ans,temp;
    int *sum = calloc(n,sizeof(int)) ;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        b[i] = a[(i+k)%n];
        sum[k]+= (i+1)*b[i];
    }
        if(ans<sum[k] || k==0){
            ans = sum[k];
        }
    }
    printf("%d",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is fine but takes too much time to execute. How can I reduce its complexity from N^2 to lower one?

Comment: The complexity of my code is N^2, and it takes too much time to execute. So, how can I reduce complexity of the my code

Comment: From https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-rotation apparently

Comment: @JohnHascall yes, can i find solutions for their questions somewhere?

Comment: Rewrite the rotated sum and you will get O(N) complexity.

Comment: @MSati doesn't that sort of defeat the whole point....?

Comment: @francis how? can you elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for sometime I got an answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n,i,k;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long long int a[n],sum[n], ans, s=0,temp;
    sum[0] =0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        sum[0]+=(i+1)*a[i];
        s+= a[i];
    }
    ans = sum[0];
    for(k=1;k<n;k++){
        temp = n*a[k-1];
        sum[k]= sum[k-1] - s + temp;
        if(ans<sum[k])
            ans = sum[k];
    }


    printf("%lld",ans);
    return 0;
}
```